# get database deleted backup via command

Tags: ubuntu, php

i have by mistake emptetied my databases for where can i get database backups.

my server team told i do not have backup activated now what to do to solve my issue .Please guide me the way to fix it.

My server is on ubantu VPS
1: is there some server command that could have files on it

Also had few more isssue

1: i am using php file upload to upload file and save content to database i do not save file to folder
2: so i thing all files uploaded be me must be on some temp folder on server .
can you guide me where to find them

Comment: You deleted your files and you don't have backups. You're finished.

Answer (score 8):

> i have by mistake emptetied my databases for where can i get database backups.

Wherevery you did put them.

> my server team told i do not have backup activated now what to do to solve my 
>   issue

YOU did not activate backups, now you whine. Sorry, there is nothing you can do.

> My server is on ubantu VPS 1: is there some server command that could have 
>   files on it

You mean magically, a command will roll back time? No. And I doubt it is ubantu.

You did what you did. Hopefully you are unimportant enough not to get sued by customers - because gross neglect and incompetence make you liable, regardless what a contract says.

Take a lesson. Maybe IT is not for you - maybe you sit down and learn best practices before repeating whatever you thought you did. But this data is gone.